# Why is there a second 'faire' in 'Je voudrais vous faire faire une radiographie.'?

Tags: grammaire, constructions-causatives

I understand the translation to roughly be:
**I would like you to do/make an X-ray.**

So wouldn't the second 'faire' result in:
**I would like you to do to make an X-ray?**

Is it something to do with the fact that 'faire une radiographie' is a specific phrase that then needs to be indicated to be done?

Comment: Follow-up question: What is the difference between *je voudrais vous refaire faire une radiographie* and *je voudrais vous faire refaire une radiographie* ;-)

Comment: I woulfd like to have you have your hair cut . If it is correct in english, the case is rather analogous.

Comment: The correct translation of the French is: **I would like you to have an X-ray done or taken**. It is not just: I would like you to have an X-ray.

Answer (score 7):

This is a passive construction.

> Je voudrais vous faire une radiographie. C'est moi qui vais vous la faire.
>
> Je voudrais vous faire faire une radiographie. C'est une troisième personne qui va la faire.

As in English with the construction *make sb do sth*.

The construction "faire faire" means externaliser, sous-traiter, concéder (un travail, un marché) à un sous-traitant.

See here https://www.anglaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-anglais-2/exercice-anglais-105563.php

for a nice explanation.

Also here (in French): https://lemondedufrancais.com/2012/02/17/construction-passive-se-faire-infinitif/

Answer (score 2):

Dimitris' answer is correct; a little more about the two uses of 'faire' in this sentence, because the confusion comes in part from those two uses in the same sentence.

*Faire* has the obvious meaning "to do, to make", as in

> Je vous fais un cafe? *(Shall I make you a coffee?)*, or
>
> Je voudrais vous faire une radiographie. *(I would like to do your X-Ray)*.

The second use of *faire* is the passive construct:

> Je vais me faire couper les cheveux. *(I'm going to get my hair cut)*
>
> Je vais vous faire faire une radiographie (*I'm going to get your X-Ray done*|*to get someone to do your X-Ray*)

So in *faire faire*, both senses of the verb as used in succession, which is often translated as "to get done".