# Position of pronoun in 'faire faire' expressions

Tags: pronoms, constructions-causatives

I came across this passage from a letter written in 1940:

> Tu me demandais où sont les immeubles incendiés le 21 juin. C’est la place de Paris côté route de Saint-Flour et route de Paulhac, la cité Lafayette jusqu’à la rue de Lyon. Je ne t’en avais pas parlé ne voulant pas de te faire faire du mauvais sang.

Is the final expression correct? I would have thought logically it would have a 'te' before both 'faires' - along the model of 'te faire te sentir mal' (or is that model not used?).

Comment: It seems as if there's a *de* that shouldn't be there. For me it should read *ne voulant pas te faire faire du mauvais sang*. If it is a written document it might well be that it slipped through the writer's watchfulness.

Comment: Agreed with None about _de_. Otherwise, _te faire faire du mauvais sang_ is legit, along the model of _te faire sentir mal_ (only one _te_).

Comment: J'ai remis la phrase originale. C'est comme ça qu'elle est écrite dans [la page](https://www.lamontagne.fr/brioude-43100/loisirs/raconte-moi-nos-prisonniers-de-40-a-brioude-haute-loire_13953207/) qui fait l'objet de la question.

Comment: Note that idiom aside (*se faire du mauvais sang*), "*faire faire*" is completely idiomatic and common. Usually meaning "make (someone) do (something)": "*J'ai oublié de lui faire faire ses devoirs.*" "*J'ai rien à lui faire faire.*" "*Je me suis fait faire un costume sur-mesure*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed expression constructed with "faire du mauvais sang" contains "faire" only in the pronominal voice.

> (Wiktionnaire) se faire du mauvais sang \sə fɛʁ dy mo.vɛ sɑ̃\
>
> (Familier) (Sens figuré) (Pronominal) S’inquiéter, se faire du souci.

Note that "de" is correct and not "du" when the main verb is negative (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22te%20faire%20de%20mauvais%20sang%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

This is regularly the case.

- Elle ne voulait pas te faire te tromper.
- Il n'avait pas envie de te faire te rappeler l'incident.
- Nous ne pensions pas vous faire vous raser régulièrement.
- etc.

However, the following combinations are not found in French.

- me faire me faire, te faire te faire, se faire se faire, nous faire nous faire, vous faire vous faire

[image]

[se faire se faire](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22se%20faire%20se%20faire%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr): all false positives

Therefore there is apparently an anomaly in the language. This is resolved by the claim that we are dealing with an idiom.

> [The verb 'faire', glossary of idioms - Page 119 - Léon Paul Blouët · 1876](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_verb_faire_glossary_of_idioms/t-4IAAAAQAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22faire+faire+du+mauvais%22&pg=PA119&printsec=frontcover)) **Faire faire du mauvais sang à quelqu'un** , to weary

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22faire%20faire%20du%20mauvais%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

The correct sentence should then be as follows.

- Je ne t’en avais pas parlé ne voulant pas te faire faire de mauvais sang. (*which might not be quite satisfying to the systematic mind, I  agree; the feeling  of anomaly seeps in and perdures.*)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146061/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-position-of-pronoun-in-faire-faire-expressions); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: What makes you say that ""de" is correct and not "du""? Your link just shows what you're looking for. ["pas du mauvais sang"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pas+du++mauvais+sang%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr%3Alang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=TnNkZJC3EuemkdUPz567iAw&ved=0ahUKEwiQlraD3Pv-AhVnU6QEHU_PDsEQ4dUDCAg&oq=%22pas+du++mauvais+sang%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAxQqwdY1UBg0E1oAHAAeACAAUOIAcsFkgECMTWYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books%22). Some examples don't make a rule. It's a case where using the one or the other is a matter of style.

Comment: @None It is not a matter of « some examples » but a matter of « much more examples » backed by a rule: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+de+mauvais+sang%2Cpas+du+mauvais+sang&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3. C'est vous qui avez mis un vote négatif ? Pour ça ?

Comment: Dans ce genre de construction on peut considérer que la négation porte soit sur le 1er faire soit sur le second, et les deux sont possibles. Besides it is misleading to write ""de" is correct and not "du" when the main verb is negative" without further details, because *de* is possible when the negation is partial. Yes negative vote is mine, "ça" as you say is not a correct information.

Comment: @None Le ngram que j'indique est très clair : c'est un nombre très inférieur de cas d'utilisation de « du » (probablement des gens pas très au courant ) ; ça me suffit.

Comment: Je pourrais aussi dire que "pas du mauvais sang" et "pas de mauvais sang" donnent des résultats plus resserrés si on fait une recherche dans gbooks, mais je préfère dire que ceux qui emploient *du* sont soit des gens qui ont spontanément dit la première chose qui leur venaient à l'esprit soit  choisi en connaissance de cause puisque **les deux sont possibles et corrects**. L'information que tu donnes est erronée.

Comment: @None Franchement, quel est l'intérêt de cette variété inutile, de cette ambigüité qui va à l'encontre d'une systématique profitable, de cet usage capricieux qui n'ajoute rien ? Aucun.

Comment: @LPH Je vous l'ai dit hier: _de_ et _du_ sont possibles, les deux s'entendent, avec une nuance de registre un peu moins soutenu pour _du_ peut-être. Je ne crois pas que ce soit "capricieux". J'irai plutôt dans la direction d'une expression régionale ou populaire pour _du_, et il y probablement d'autres exemples avec la même nuance.

Comment: @Frank Oh oui, c'est même mentionné dans des grammaires : dans le parler, plutôt familier, les gens tendent à ne pas appliquer la règle et ils utilisent « du » (Kalmbach, je crois).

Comment: @Frank Ce n'est pas uniquement une question de registre. Dans la phrase de l'exemple *du mauvais sang* n'est lié qu'au second *faire*, et ce verbe n'est pas à la forme négative. En fait les deux choix sont possibles, et il n'existe à ma connaissance aucune règle l'interdisant.  Et n'oublions pas les cas de négation partielle où il faut parfois faire jouer la logique (*Le bon usage* parle de style et de sens). La seule « règle » qui existe à ma connaissance c'est en présence de la négation absolue.

Comment: @none Comment dites-vous ? « pas leur faire courir des risques » ? Regardez donc cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+leur+faire+courir+de%2Cpas+leur+faire+courir+des&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @None OK - je n'étais pas bien sûr pour la nuance de registre, que j'avais encadrée de moultes "peut-être" et "plutôt" :-)

Comment: @LPH _je ne leur fais pas courir de risques_.

Comment: @LPH De manière générale, LPH, les ngrams sont certes instructifs, et la francophonie est vaste et il y a toujours des nuances qui échappent, mais je ne vois pas pourquoi vous voulez vous battre avec des gens qui pratiquent la langue tous les jours ... Vous ne nous convaincrez pas que nous avons "faux" parce que les n-grams ou la grammaire disent autrement. Mieux vaut tenir compte de tous les points de vue.

Comment: @Frank Je ne me bats jamais quand je discute mais je n'hésite pas à discuter longuement si c'est utile ;  vous pouvez nier l'évidence, mais la forme correcte _et_ celle que la logique recommande reste « de » ; « du » dans cette construction est une divergence que l'on trouve dans un parler relâché. Je ne cherche pas à convaincre, seulement à ne pas laisser n'importe qui me convaincre sans bonne raison.

Comment: On peut faire ça pendant des heures.... on ne trouve pas ce qu'on ne cherche pas, tout dépend de ce qu'on cherche et comment on le cherche (comme je l'ai déjà dit d'ailleurs) ["pas courir des risques"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pas+courir+des+risques%22&tbm=bks&ei=SAVlZKXBEKevkdUPvp23-AQ&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwilheie5_z-AhWnV6QEHb7ODU84ChDy0wN6BAgOEAc&biw=1866&bih=909&dpr=1), certains où j'aurais moi-même mis *de* mais je ne dis pas que ceux qui ont mis *des* sont dans l'erreur.

Comment: @none Je ne nie pas que cette tendance existe, mais regardez à quel point elle est minoritaire, et bien que ceux qui utilisent « des » soient des gens instruits l'énorme majorité qui suit la règle n'est pas moins instruite. Je crois que l'on doive pencher pour la majorité instruite. [ne pas courir de risques, ne pas courir des risques](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+courir+de+risques%2Cpas+courir+des+risques&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @LPH Et la conclusion est? Nous ne nions aucune évidence (j'ai bien dit "_Mieux vaut tenir compte de tous les points de vue_"), et nous ne sommes pas _n'importe qui_, mais des gens qui utilisent la langue tout les jours en tant que langue maternelle, donc nous sommes aussi un témoignage valide et qu'on ne peut pas ignorer.

Comment: @Frank À mon avis, selon le fait que les  personnes instruites ne sont pas  nécessairement des linguistes ni même nécessairement des personne qui auraient un sens profond de leur propre langue, la conclusion serait que la règle est  appliquée, mais pas trop bien, cela du fait que c'est une règle subtile et difficile à internaliser ; cependant, il est important de la préserver par ce que c'est une règle qui apporte  au langage une finesse qu'il serait dommage de perdre. Le témoignage a peu de valeur dans le processus démocratique.

Comment: @LPH Peu importe. Ce que nous disons et ce que nous écrivons sont les n-grams de demain. Merci de marginaliser notre témoignage sous couvert de "démocratie" - une compréhension intéressante de la démocratie. Mais de toute façon, encore une fois, la langue galope bien en avant de toutes les règles et vous n'y pouvez rien.

Comment: @Frank C'est bien vrai, la langue change en permanence,  et l'individu n'y peut rien ,et on doit se soumettre au choix qu'à fait une majorité quand ce choix a éclipsé tous les autres (sans quoi on ne peut pas s'exprimer).

Answer (score 5):

1. *Is the final expression correct?*

   No, the sentence *Je ne t’en avais pas parlé ne voulant pas **de** te faire faire du mauvais sang.* is incorrect. There is an extraneous ***de*** after *pas*.
2. *I would have thought logically it would have a 'te' before both 'faires' - along the model of 'te faire te sentir mal' (or is that model not used?).*

   That would be logical but a second ***te*** is not required nor used in that case. *Te faire faire* works regardless of whether the second *faire* is pronominal or not. With other verbs, both forms are found although they are all rare, especially the first one (bold is mine):

   > *Et, pour **te faire sentir** mieux, reprit Lucas, moi non plus je n'arrive pas à trouver quoi que ce soit en ce qui concerne l'énigme...*
   > Diane Le Bel, *La mission de Gogolinette*, 2011

   > *Si cela peut **te faire te sentir** mieux, je te préfère nettement comme tu es maintenant, me dit-il doucement lorsque je rouvre les yeux pour le regarder.*
   > Tara Sivec, *Des cris dans l'inconnu*, 2021

   In either case, all of the occurences are from the 21st century and are mostly found in books translated from English so I guess native writers avoid these turns for being to heavy.

---

The expected sentence is:

> *Je ne t’en avais pas parlé ne voulant pas te faire faire du mauvais sang.*

Here are some alternatives:

> *Je ne t’en avais pas parlé ne voulant pas que tu te fasses du mauvais sang (à cause de moi).*
> *Je ne t’en avais pas parlé parce que je ne voulais pas que tu te fasses du mauvais sang (à cause de moi).*
> *Je ne t’en avais pas parlé pour éviter de te faire faire du mauvais sang.*
> *Je ne t’en avais pas parlé de crainte de te faire faire du mauvais sang.*

See also: [Why is there a second 'faire' in 'Je voudrais vous faire faire une radiographie.'?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41954/why-is-there-a-second-faire-in-je-voudrais-vous-faire-faire-une-radiographie)

Comment: En fait, vu la discussion aussi sur _vouloir_ et _s'en vouloir_, je me suis pris à construire: _je voulais ne pas m'en vouloir d'avoir voulu te faire faire du mauvais sang_, qui me paraît sans faute ;-)

Comment: @Frank *Pour vouloir, il faut le vouloir et pour vouloir vouloir, il faut encore le vouloir, et ce, jusqu'à l'infini. Le vouloir bien portant le vouloir simple et indivis qui n'a pas perdu la fonction du commencement. Ce vouloir résistant à toute les agrégations commence par vouloir.* Vladimir Jankélévitch

Comment: Je concède. Battu par Jankélévitch - j'aurais pu faire pire :-)